# Creating a view: error MSG 156, Level 15, State 1

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE VIEW titles_borrowed
AS 
    SELECT b.booktitle, o.bookid
    FROM books b 
    INNER JOIN o borrowed ON b.bookid = o.bookid
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to run this:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure titles_borrowed, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 5]
> Invalid object name 'o'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch o and borrowed:

```
CREATE VIEW titles_borrowed
AS SELECT b.booktitle,o.bookid
FROM books b 
INNER JOIN borrowed o 
ON b.bookid = o.bookid
```

First the table then the alias.